# Print specific line from all files in folder

Tags: python

I have several txt files that I would like to search and print a single line if it starts with certain words (<meta property="og:description" content=). I currently have this code, which I want to search just each file in the specified folder:

```
import glob

filepath = '/Volumes/hardDrive/Folder/files/*'

corpus = glob.glob(filepath)
for textfile in corpus:    
    f = open(textfile, 'r')    
    pTxt = []    
    for ln in f:        
        if ln.startswith(r'<meta property="og:description" content='):            
            pTxt.append(ln[2:])        
        print(pTxt)
```

Right now, it’s returning [] (without stopping) when it shouldn’t be, which it’s also returning when I shorten the text to “<meta” (which should return several more results). How can I fix this so that it only prints the target line from each file?

Comment: Wouldn’t `grep` be a more straight-forward approach to this?

Comment: This is how it's done, pretty standard hard coded searching since you don't want something a regex could help with. Grep is nice but this could be used as part of a larger script.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your function doesn't *return* anything.  It prints something and appends to a list, but it does not return.  At least the part you've shown doesn't.  And do you really mean to create a new list for every single file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

filepath = '/home/filepath/*.txt'


for textfile in glob.glob(filepath):
    pTxt = []
    f = open(textfile, 'r').readlines()
    for ln in f:        
        if ln.startswith(r'<meta property="og:description" content='):            
            pTxt.append(ln)        
    print(pTxt)
```

This Should Work Fine

Comment: It still is returning empty brackets, but it stops now.